# sudo as a user that has sudo rights?

Tags: linux, debian, bash, alias, bashrc

Alice has sudo rights.
Bob does not (this is not changeable), but does know the password to Alice's account.

If Bob wants to perform administrative commands he must:

1. `su alice`
2. fill in Alice's password for su
3. `sudo whoami`
4. fill in Alice's sudo password
5. command gets executed with super user rights

To shorten this I use: `su -m alice -c 'sudo whoami'`.

However, I want to build an alias command that replaces with this tedious command with just the regular sudo command.

So I made this: `alias sudo="su -m alice -c 'sudo $@'"`.

2 caveats:

- It doesn't work
- It always asks for Alice's su password, the sudo password it does remember

How can I do this better?

Thanks!

Comment: Aliases don't take parameters. Use a function instead. I believe `su` never remembers passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the sudoers configuration.  If "Defaults  requiretty" is set this method wont work.

```
suds () { 
    ARGS="$@"
    /bin/su -m alice -c "/usr/bin/sudo  TERM=xterm $ARGS"
}
```

A few comments about this

1. It will always ask for alices's password to authenticate the su.
2. When a variable is offset with single quotes it will not normally be expanded.
3. I tend to use functions rather than aliases they allow me to add a bit more logic to the transformations.
4. This is a bad idea from a security perspective.  Make sure this doesn't violate local policies before implementing it.

Rik